# Setting inner property of an object with an inner method - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I started this project just for fun (inspired by the Conway's Game of Life). In my project, I have a file for the cell (defined as an object) and other for the game (universe) where the rules are set so the cell can play. The cell object is defined like this:

```
const cell = {
    x_birth: 0,
    y_birth: 0,
    alive: false,
    live: function() {
        fill(100);
        square((WIDTH/F)*x, (HIGH/F)*y, (WIDTH/F), (HIGH/F));
    },
    die: function() {
        fill(255);
        square((WIDTH/F)*x, (HIGH/F)*y, (WIDTH/F), (HIGH/F));
    },
    move: function(x_var, y_var) {

        if (this.alive == false){

            x = this.x_birth;
            y = this.y_birth;

            this.alive = true; // Bug?

            this.live();

        } else { //... }}}
```

WIDTH, HIGH and F are global constants from the other main file. 
The problem I have is that when I create two objects with 'Object.create(cell)' in the main file, just one of the cells moves. It appears that when one of the cells executes its function 'move()', it does it correctly, setting it's property 'alive' to 'true' when the other cell (object) doesn't. I though that this may be the problem, but then I searched and I didn't find why this should be the issue.

If you want, you can download the files from my repo: https://github.com/Atotem/Game.git . There you will understand what i mean. I'm open to all suggestions.

PD: I'm using p5.js libraries.

Comment: Don't use global variables like `x` and `y`. Make them local variables and pass them as parameters to `this.live() and `this.die()`

Comment: My men you genius. Thank you so much.